# Handling Model Binding Errors when using [FromBody] in .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-2.1

I am trying to understand how I can intercept and handle model binding errors in .net core.

I want to do this:

```
    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] Thing value)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Handle Error Here
        }
    }
```

Where the Model for "Thing" is:

```
public class Thing
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

However if I pass in an invalid amount like:

```
{ 
   "description" : "Cats",
   "amount" : 21.25
}
```

I get an error back like this:

> {"amount":["Input string '21.25' is not a valid integer. Path 'amount', line 1, position 38."]}

Without the controller code ever being hit.

How can I customise the error being sent back? (as basically I need to wrap this serialisation error in a larger error object)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So, I missed this before but I have found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#automatic-http-400-responses

That if you use the

```
[ApiController]
```

attribute on your controller, it will automatically handle serialisation errors and provide the 400 response, equivalent to:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

You can turn this behaviour off in the Startup.cs like this:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    });
```

If you are looking to customise the response, a better option is to use a InvalidModelStateResponseFactory, which is a delegate taking an ActionContext and returning an IActionResult which will be called to handle serialisation errors.

See this example:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext => 
    {
        var errors = actionContext.ModelState
            .Where(e => e.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
            .Select(e => new Error
            {
            Name = e.Key,
            Message = e.Value.Errors.First().ErrorMessage
            }).ToArray();

        return new BadRequestObjectResult(errors);
    }
});
```

Comment: The better approach is to supply a custom handler via `options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`. That way, you still don't need to check `ModelState.IsValid` all over the place, and you can still return your custom response.

Comment: Sorry. Missed the last line. But, yeah, use the `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`. That's the way to go.

Comment: This is the best answer I could find. However if there is an error during model binding - like trying to bind an integer to a guid, aspnet bypasses the InvalidModelStateResponseFactory and returns the default 400 bad response. I can't find any way to customise the erro. using SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter just gives you a null model and no info on why the model didn't bind.

Comment: If you are gonna implement new `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` make sure you DON'T set `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter` to true it must remains false.

Answer (score 3):

The framework uses Model Binders to map the request strings into a complex object, so my guess is that you will need to create a Custom Model Binder. Please refer [Custom Model Binding in ASP.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

But before that, an easier way to try would be to try Binder attributes in your models. **BindRequired** attribute adds a model state error if binding cannot occur. So you can modify your model as :

```
public class Thing 
{
    [BindRequired]
    public string Description {get;set;}

    [BindRequired]
    public int Amount {get;set;}
}
```

If that doesn't work for you, then you can try to create a custom model binder. An example from the article :

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(AuthorEntityBinder))]
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GitHub { get; set; }
    public string Twitter { get; set; }
    public string BlogUrl { get; set; }
}

public class AuthorEntityBinder : IModelBinder
{
   private readonly AppDbContext _db;
   public AuthorEntityBinder(AppDbContext db)
   {
       _db = db;
   }

public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    if (bindingContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
    }

    var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;

    // Try to fetch the value of the argument by name
    var valueProviderResult =
        bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);

    if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(modelName,
        valueProviderResult);

    var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

    // Check if the argument value is null or empty
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    int id = 0;
    if (!int.TryParse(value, out id))
    {
        // Non-integer arguments result in model state errors
        bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(
                                modelName,
                                "Author Id must be an integer.");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // Model will be null if not found, including for 
    // out of range id values (0, -3, etc.)
    var model = _db.Authors.Find(id);
    bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
}
```

You might also want to look at [Model Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2)