# ASP.NET WebAPI Global error handling filter not working when model binding error occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, error-handling, model-binding

I wrote web API in .NET Framework. I made a global error filter.

```
 public class UnhandledExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
 {
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
       //log somewhere 
       //Make user friendly error message
    }
 }
```

And I added it to global filters

```
config.Filters.Add(new UnhandledExceptionFilter());
```

This works fine when an error occurs in the controller. But it does not work when an error occurs in default model binding.
Let's say I have one action and it gets one `DateTime` parameter.

```
 public class MyController: ApiController
 {
    public override void CheckBirthdate(DateTime birthdate)
    {
       throw new Exception("Test");
    }
 }
```

If I call `MyController/CheckBirthdate?birthdate=03/05/2021` like that my global error handling works. But I call `MyController/CheckBirthdate?birthdate=test` like that my global error handling not works. I get back error like that

> Could not convert string to DateTime: test. Path 'birthdate'

Why global error handling filter can not catch it? How can I solve it?.

Comment: I ran into this issue too and solved it based on this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55101315/2151022